# Php pdo result array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have a select to a database what should get a number and display it, but display just `array`

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT score FROM people WHERE email='gasd3z@yaho.com'");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $result;
```

What can I do to display that number?

Comment: `print_r($result);` maybe? just maybe... (I also bet (5$) on it that you don't have error reporting turned on: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`)

Comment: Works with print_r but I dont want to display a array "Array ( [0] => Array ( [score] => 3 ) ) " I want a number.

Comment: `echo $result['score']`

Comment: Also, since you are not binding any parameters in your sql query you an write it all in one line `$sth = $conn->query("SELECT score FROM people WHERE email='gasd3z@yaho.com'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @Gabriel Maybe you want to read about some basic array stuff: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: You have nothing TO prepare. Here => `$sth = $conn->query` then loop over your query.

Comment: works the same equal

Comment: I use json_encode and give me [{"score":"3"}], how convert in a simple numer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't prepare anything so you don't need to use prepared statements just use query like this:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT score FROM people WHERE email='gasd3z@yaho.com'");
foreach($result as $row)
    echo $row['score'];
```

Comment: @Gabriel 1. Please mark sure you show us your **full** and **real** code in your question 2. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` 3. Add error mode for PDO right after your connection: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is wrong, but not much.
When you're doing `fetchAll()`, you're getting all of the rows matching query from the database.

The answer is

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT score FROM people WHERE email=:email");
$sth->execute([':email' => 'gasd3z@yaho.com']);
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->closeCursor();
echo $result['score'];
```

And don't forget that `prepare()` is for preparing statements, so you better want to have user data in query just like in my example. If you don't want to process any values in query, use `query()` or `exec()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can print out arrays with `print_r($result)` or `var_dump($result)`. Echoing only prints out the type.

Also, if you only need to print out a specific line, do it like `echo $result['score'];`